# Angularjs $scope.$apply is not updating the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angularjs based view is not getting updated after change in model object, even after using $apply method. Please tell me if I am doing something wrong, here is the code. After referring various questions and answers, I tried by calling scope.$apply() after changing object and changed model object with in scope.$apply method, either way didn't work for me.

```
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.status" ng-click="toggleUser(user)"/></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table

scope.sendStatus = function(user) {
    //Send to server
    user.status = false;
};

scope.toggleUser = function(user) {
    if (!user.status) {
        bootbox.confirm("Do you want to enable user " + user.name, function(r) {
            if(r) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.sendStatus(user);
                    });
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    } else {
        bootbox.confirm("Do you want to disable user " + user.name, function(r) {
            if(r) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.sendStatus(user);
                    });
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: start with switching to angular's `$timeout` that does `$apply` for you: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout

Comment: @akonsu, no luck, still view is not getting updated, here is the changed code, `$timeout(function(){
                        scope.sendStatus(user);
                    }, 2000);`

Comment: if you set up a plnkr.co page I can debug it for you

Comment: is the user bound to the scope? e.g. is there something in your controller that looks like this: scope.user ?

Comment: Okay, I could solve the problem, I had enclosed checkbox in `<a>` tag, somehow that is impacting the checkbox functionality, after removing `<a>` tag and after making changes calling scope.$apply() is working fine. Thanks all